# I need to convert vowels to the "@" symbol in Scala

Tags: scala

The idea of this program is to read lines in and take out all vowels and replace them with the "@" character. Input will stop with the user typing "--quit--" and it will return those lines with the function applied to them. I can't figure out what the syntax should be for the part of the function I've included "lst.map("aeiouAEIOU" => '@')" . I think I'm missing something.

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

def readList: List[String] = {
  val n = readLine
  if (n == "--quit--") {
    return Nil   
  } else {
    return n::readList
  }
}

def vowelsToAt(lst: List[String]): List[String] = {

  lst.map("aeiouAEIOU" => '@')


}

val wordList = readList
println(vowelsToAt(wordList).mkString("\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `lst.map("aeiouAEIOU" => '@')` you can use

```
lst.map(_.map(c => if ("aeiouAEIOU" contains c) '@' else c))
```

The inner `map` transforms a string char-by-char by replacing vowels with `@`s, and the outer `map` applies this transformation to every element of the list.

Your expression `"aeiouAEIOU" => '@'` is not valid, the left hand side must be an arbitrary char (the argument of your lambda), and not the string containing the chars you want to map. Another possibility that is similiar to your approach (but a bit convoluted):

```
list.map(_.map {
  case 'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' | 'A' | 'E' | 'I' | 'O' | 'U' => '@'
  case c => c
})
```

One side note: In your method `readList`, you do not have to use `return`, as the last statement is also interpreted as the return value.

Comment: In the example you provided:

"lst.map(_.map(c => if ("aeiouAEIOU" contains c) '@' else c))"

 what is the "c"?

Comment: It is the parameter of your lambda. The expression `c => if ("aeiouAEIOU" contains c) '@' else c` is of type `Char => Char` and therefore takes a char `c` (you can choose any other name) and returns "@" if `c` is a vowel or `c`itself otherwise.